# Comment icon not updating after approval in blog site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I set up a workflow for comments in a blog site. Only after approval should a comment be posted in the blog.

To test, I created a comment and received an email to approve. I approved the comment and it was added to the list. When I click on the comment icon it displays the new comment, but the little comment icon didnt update to show a new comment. It still said (0 comments). What do I need to do to have this update?

Thanks, Ninel

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like caching somewhere along the line. To be sure, try Ctrl-F5 in most browsers and see if it updates.